# Why is this call ambiguous?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, c#-3.0, extension-methods

Can anyone explain, why does the following code produce the error? (Compiling in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008)

```
class Base1 {  };
class Base2 {  }

interface I1   {   }
interface I2   {   }

class C : I1, I2 { }

static class Program
{

    static T M1<T>(this T t, I1 x) where T : Base1
    {
        return t;
    }

    static T M1<T>(this T t, I2 x) where T : Base2
    {
        return t;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Base1 b1 = new Base1();
        C c = new C();
        b1.M1(c);
    }
}
```

the error is

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: '`ConsoleApplication1.Program.M1<ConsoleApplication1.Base1>(ConsoleApplication1.Base1, ConsoleApplication1.I1)`' and '`ConsoleApplication1.Program.M1<ConsoleApplication1.Base1>(ConsoleApplication1.Base1, ConsoleApplication1.I2)`'

I thought the compiler could distinguish between two methods using the "where" clauses

Comment: I don't think generic constraints qualify as part of the method signature.

Comment: Generic constraints do not participate in overload resolution.

Comment: This is unfortunately a duplicate question. The gist of it is that generic constraints are not considered when finding viable matching method overloads, and the compiler fails before considering those. There are numerous questions here on SO already about this, I just need to find the right search keywords.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Constraints are not part of the signature for methods and thus are not used for resolution.

Answer (score 3):

Constraints are not part of the signature. For details see [Eric Lippert article on the topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Constraint  cant be use to resolve association.